# React - Accessing nested objects in returned data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm using `fetch` to return some data from a local API. I'm able to return the data and set the state. However, in my `render()` function when using `map` and attempting to access anything deeper than the top level object in the data I get an `undefined` error. I can correctly log any level of the data that I want to the console, but I don't have access to it within the rendered component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    verifications: []
  }
}

componentWillMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/verifications')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((verifications) => {
      this.setState({verifications})
      console.log(this.state);
    });
}
```

and in my render

```
{this.state.verifications.map(verification =>
  <div key={verification._id}>
    <ReviewListItem
      hasAvatar={true}
      imageUrl={verification.supplier.logo}
      title={verification.supplier.companyName}
      description={verification.tasks.length}
    />
  </div>
)}
```

This is the error I get:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'logo' of null`

I've searched high and low for an answer to this, but I feel like I must be approaching this wrong. I come from Angular 1, and I'm extremely new to React. Maybe I'm having a hard time grasping the concepts.

Here's my data:

```
[
{
"_id": 1000,
"supplier": {
"_id": 1000,
"companyName": "ACME Business Ventures",
"logo": "/images/logos/suppliers/acme.jpg",
"avettaId": "ADS83J",
"brandColor": "#563E5E",
"clients": [],
"locations": [],
"primaryContact": {},
"address": {},
"createdAt": "2017-06-30T17:42:23.479Z"
},
"tasks": [
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "How long have you been in business?",
"answer": "18 Years",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "Have you had any fatalities in the last 3 years?",
"answer": "No",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Diversity Questionnaire",
"question": "Are you a minority-owned business?",
"answer": "Yes",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Sustainability Questionnaire",
"question": "What percentage of your business runs on renewable energy?",
"answer": "About 55%, but that's expected to climb to 80% by next year.",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
}
]
},
{
"_id": 2000,
"supplier": null,
"tasks": [
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "How long have you been in business?",
"answer": "18 Years",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "Have you had any fatalities in the last 3 years?",
"answer": "No",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Diversity Questionnaire",
"question": "Are you a minority-owned business?",
"answer": "Yes",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Sustainability Questionnaire",
"question": "What percentage of your business runs on renewable energy?",
"answer": "About 55%, but that's expected to climb to 80% by next year.",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
}
]
},
{
"_id": 3000,
"supplier": null,
"tasks": [
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "How long have you been in business?",
"answer": "18 Years",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "Have you had any fatalities in the last 3 years?",
"answer": "No",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Diversity Questionnaire",
"question": "Are you a minority-owned business?",
"answer": "Yes",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Sustainability Questionnaire",
"question": "What percentage of your business runs on renewable energy?",
"answer": "About 55%, but that's expected to climb to 80% by next year.",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
}
]
},
{
"_id": 4000,
"supplier": null,
"tasks": [
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "How long have you been in business?",
"answer": "18 Years",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "PQF General",
"question": "Have you had any fatalities in the last 3 years?",
"answer": "No",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Diversity Questionnaire",
"question": "Are you a minority-owned business?",
"answer": "Yes",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
},
{
"form": "Sustainability Questionnaire",
"question": "What percentage of your business runs on renewable energy?",
"answer": "About 55%, but that's expected to climb to 80% by next year.",
"status": "incomplete",
"attachment": "",
"comments": []
}
]
}
]
```

Comment: verification.supplier is a number, not an object. it doesnt look like those fields you are trying to access exist anywhere in the data

Comment: Ah crap... whoops. Posted my seed file. Edited to show the actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your suppliers is null (at least one). Consider using something like `imageUrl={verification.supplier ? verification.supplier.logo : null}` instead of `imageUrl={verification.supplier.logo}`.

Comment: Well... crap. :-( Pardon me while I go pout in the corner. That's ridiculous. I guess it pays to look at the entire object first. I never made it past the first one and just assumed that the rest were there. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Similar things happened to me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The second index of your array has `supplier: null`. You can check that supplier exists first

```
{this.state.verifications.map(verification =>
  <div key={verification._id}>
    <ReviewListItem
      hasAvatar={true}
      imageUrl={verification.supplier && verification.supplier.logo}
      title={verification.supplier && verification.supplier.companyName}
      description={verification.tasks.length}
    />
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

The supplier is clearly null in your json snippet:

```
"supplier": null,
```

Thus it obviously fails :)

I believe angular automatically checks for nulls in expressions like this: `foo.bar.baz.something.deeply.nested` — so if anything is null the result will be null — in react, (and in js in general)‚ you need to check for nulls by yourself.